# How do I get a unique named list?

Tags: r

This is a simple question and I think I can probably re-invent the wheel and write something custom but I'm sure there must be an easy way to do this that I can't think of at the moment. Suppose I have a list:

```
l <- list("NY"=10001, "CT"=10002, "CT"=10002)
```

I would like a list:

```
list("NY"=10001, "CT"=10002)
```

I tried to use `unique(l)` but it just returns:

```
list(10001, 10002)
```

How do I get a unique list but preserve the names assigned to the values?

Comment: What happens if you have `l <- list("NY"=10001, "CT"=10002, "CT"=10002, "CT"=999)` ?

Comment: one solution could be `l[!duplicated(unlist(l))]`

Comment: @zx8754 - that can't happen. Each string is mapped to 1 number

Comment: Still a very interesting problem posed by @zx8754

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using *duplicated*:

```
l[ !duplicated(l) ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Given that

> *Each string is mapped to 1 number*

we can do:

```
l[unique(names(l))]
```

*Edit:*, another alternative

```
tapply(l, names(l), `[`, 1)
```

Comment: I like this way too but !duplicated seems straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Try the duplicated function:

```
l=list("NY"=10001, "CT"=10002, "CT"=10002)
l[!duplicated(l)]
```

Results in:

```
$NY
[1] 10001

$CT
[1] 10002
```